# Retrofit2 call for android google maps Api not working

Tags: android, api, kotlin, maps, retrofit

I am using retrofit in an android project in order to be able to call the google maps api and get an autocomplete suggestion of places. I am passing an address (of type String parameter) for the call. The RetrofitCaller class has the start method as shown below:

```
private val BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/"
fun start(address: String) {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
    val placeAutoCompleteAPI: PlaceAutoCompleteAPI =
        retrofit.create(PlaceAutoCompleteAPI::class.java)
    val call: Call<PredictionResponse?>? = placeAutoCompleteAPI.loadPredictions(address)
    call?.enqueue(this)
}
```

The PlacesAutoCompleteApi has the http request with the loadPredictions function:

```
@GET("api/place/autocomplete/json?types=address&key=AIzaSyApUcl88FpB4xHH0HS9FW4WC4wHaJu3VVU")
fun loadPredictions(@Query("input") address: String?): Call<PredictionResponse?>?
```

However I am unable to get a response from the server. I am using a PredictionResponse and a Prediction class for the type of data returned from the server query.

What is wrong with the code or the methodology?

Thank you in advance,
Lampros

Comment: Why are you not using the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I use place autocomplete for editText and it works like this:

Create google cloud account and get yourself an API key (you probably have that if you want to use autocomplete). There you set for what package the API has to work.

In manifest add the following:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

In gradle use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

and if somebody presses the edittext there's just 3 lines of code:

```
val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.ADDRESS)
                    val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields).build(this@AddPlaceActivity)
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

you can delete lat and lng values if you don't need them.